# Выставить selected в html документе с помощью JS и Url строки

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Имеется главная страница в которой выставляются фильтры. Все списки параметров фильтра записываются от запроса к базе данных. Пример

```
$data['attr_colors'] = $this->model_catalog_form->getAttributs(14);
```

И выводятся вот так

```
    <div class="params input_price one_group" >
        <select name="count_modules" placeholder="" tabindex=3>
    <option>Количество модулей</option>
      <?php foreach($attr_modules as $attr_module) {
         echo "<option>".$attr_module["text"]."</option>";
       }
      ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Вопрос, как выставлять выбранный параметр в option (selected). Заранее спасибо
(возможно как-то получать из строки выбранные параметр)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение на Angular

```
<select class="plating" ng-model="main.sel" ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in main.list" ng-disabled="main.viewMode">
</select>
```

JS

```
this.list = [{
"name": "one"
},
{
"name": "two"
},
{
"name": "three"
}
];
this.sel = this.list[1]; //будет выбрано
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.